# Does the object stored/retrieved using jQuery .data() have any knowledge of the DOM element it is attached to?

Tags: jquery

Consider the following example:

HTML:

```
<div id="cool-div"></div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
var ComplexObject = function() {

   this.Append = function(textToAppend) {
      //append text to the div that this is "attached" to
   };

};

var obj = new ComplexObject();
$("#cool-div").data("o", obj);
```

Is there a way for the ComplexObject() to know which DOM element it is "attached" to - in this case the DIV "#cool-div".  I would like to add text to "#cool-div" using just the ComplexObject() class ... but I don't think I can, or at least I haven't been able to tackle it.

Comment: I think you may need to .proxy() this one. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object doesn't know by default which element(s) it's attached to - the data can be anything, so jquery wouldn't know how to tell the object when it attaches it.

You can write a wapper around `.data` to make it comply with your requirement, for example:

```
$.fn.dataaware = function(key, value) {
    this.data(key, value);

    if (value instanceof ComplexObject)
        value.setContext(this);
}
```

You might also want to wrap `.removeData` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this probably isn't the sexy, built-in type answer you're looking for, but you could always assign it explicitly with something like this:

```
var ComplexObject = function(domElt) {

   this.domElt = domElt;

   this.Append = function(textToAppend) {
      //append text to the div that this is "attached" to
   };

};

var obj = new ComplexObject($('#cool-div"));
```

Hopefully that can at least help!

Answer (score 1):

No, ComplexObject does not know unless you tell it. You could do something like this:

```
var ComplexObject = function() {

  this.Append = function(textToAppend) {
      //append text to the div that this is "attached" to
  };

  this.elem = '';

};

var obj = new ComplexObject();

$("#cool-div").data("o", obj);
obj.elem = $("#cool-div"); // or obj.elem = $("#cool-div")[0]; if you want the node
```